# Panel should fade in then a new scene should load in

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

When a trigger is activated a panel should fade in then a new scene should load. Unfortunately only one of these things happens.

I would like one to happen after the other.

```
public void transitionpef()

{
    StartCoroutine(panelfadewhite());
}


public IEnumerator panelfadewhite()

{

    float ElapsedTime = 0f;
    float TotalTime = 2f;

   while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)

    {
      ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
      panel.color = Color.Lerp(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0), new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
      SceneManager.LoadScene("selection_ui", LoadSceneMode.Single);
      yield return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have your returns in the wrong spot. Try this:

```
public IEnumerator panelfadewhite()
{
    float ElapsedTime = 0f;
    float TotalTime = 2f;
    while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)
    {
          ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
          panel.color = Color.Lerp(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0), new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));
          yield return null;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("selection_ui", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    yield return null;    
}
```